# ошибка Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fname')

Tags: массивы, таблицы

вот такой код есть, но возникает ошибка на этапе cell1.innerHTML... скажите, пожалуйста, почему возникает проблема с массивом?

```
function showData ()
            {
            getData();
            var tbl = document.getElementById ("table");
           
           
            for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
            {
                var r = tbl.insertRow();
                var cell1=r.insertCell();
                var cell2=r.insertCell();
                var cell2=r.insertCell();
            }
                cell1.innerHTML =arr[i].fname;
                cell2.innerHTML = arr[i].lname;
                cell3.innerHTML = arr[i].kname;

            }
```

Comment: забыл дописать, что массив объявлен, просто в другой части кода

Comment: уже не нужно, я сам понял